# Rewriting Sequential model using Functional API

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to rewrite a Sequential model of [Network In Network CNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4400) using Functional API. I use it with CIFAR-10 dataset. The Sequential model trains without a problem, but Functional API model gets stuck. I probably missed something when rewriting the model.

Here's a reproducible example:

Dependencies:

```python
from keras.models import Model, Input, Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout, Activation
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.datasets import cifar10
```

Loading the dataset:

```python
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train / 255.
x_test = x_test / 255.
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)
input_shape = x_train[0,:,:,:].shape
```

Here's the working Sequential model:

```python
model = Sequential()

#mlpconv block1
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='valid',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#mlpconv block2
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#mlpconv block3
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(10, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Compile and train:

```python
model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['acc']) 

_ = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=32, 
          epochs=200, verbose=1,validation_split=0.2)
```

In three epochs the model gets close to 50% validation accuracy.

Here's the same model rewritten using Functional API:

```python
model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

#mlpconv block1
x = Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='valid')(model_input)
x = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

#mlpconv block2
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (1, 1), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

#mlpconv block3
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='valid')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (1, 1), activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(10, (1, 1), activation='relu')(x)

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Activation(activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(model_input, x, name='nin_cnn')
```

This model is then compiled using the same parameters as the Sequential model. When trained, the training accuracy gets stuck at `0.10`, meaning the model doesn't get better and randomly chooses one of 10 classes.

What did I miss when rewriting the model? When calling `model.summary()` the models look identical except for the explicit `Input` layer in the Functional API model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `activation` in the final conv layer solves the problem:

```
x = Conv2D(10, (1, 1))(x)
```

Still not sure why the Sequential model works fine with activation in that layer.

Comment: @desertnaut Do you mean softmax after `GlobalAveragePooling2D`? It is just an alternative to a final FC layer with softmax.

Comment: It work with me, But I did not understand why to remove activation function from the final conv layer?! Could you please justify?

Comment: @N.IT this was a while ago... Can't really justify why it worked that way. My be related to how global pooling works